# The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again. in voyager shared host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, voyager

When I run Voyager admin page in xampp windows that path is localhost/admin it works. but when I run it in shared host it is not working. It shows

> The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again

I already checked `login.blade.php` inside `/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/`.

`{{ csrf_field() }}` is available that login form. But still shows the error.

How to solve this? Please help.